# How to create derby database using java code

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, derby

I'm working on java Hospital Management System project. I have to create dynamic database with "query" .. I know how to connect the database in netbeans

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/{databasename}","{username}","{password}");
```

but i have to add dynamic doctors so my each doctor has its own database which contains admit patients table and non admit's patients row(oneTable named nonAdmits)
but I stucked at creating dynamic database **because we can't connect derby without port, databasename, username and password** but in my case i'm going to create dynamic doctor with the help of admin so how can i create dynamic database in ***Derby-netbeans***

in short :
something like in mysql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DB_NAME;
```

Comment: You add `;create=true` at the end of the ConnectionURL to create the database if it doesn't yet exist. Is that the question you are asking?

Comment: yes means i have to connect with the server and create my first database related to my project.. something like that .. means i dont want to specify the database in the getConnection() function..

Comment: Possibly this is a *terminology* problem, and what you are looking for is the ability to have multiple *schemas* in a single *database*. See https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsqlj31580.html

Answer (score -2):

**Simple example : create a data base and a table based on input given by the user and insert some data in the table then fetch data and drop the table :**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
        String dbName;
        String tableName;

        System.out.println("Enter the Data Base name :");
        dbName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the table name :");
        tableName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Starting");

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        System.out.println("Loaded the appropriate driver.");

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", "user1");
        props.put("password", "user1");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName + ";create=true", props);
        System.out.println("Connected to and created database " + dbName);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        s.execute("create table " + tableName + "(num int, addr varchar(40))");
        System.out.println("Created table " + tableName);
        s.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values (1,'LONDON')");
        s.execute("insert into  " + tableName + " values (2,'PARIS')");

        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT num, addr FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY num");
        System.out.println("NUM" + "   " + "ADDRESS");
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "       " + rs.getString(2));
        rs.next();
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "       " + rs.getString(2));

        s.execute("drop table " + tableName);
        System.out.println("Dropped table " + tableName);

        rs.close();
        s.close();
        System.out.println("Closed result set and statement");

        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Committed transaction and closed connection");
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Enter the Data Base name :
db
Enter the table name :
tb
Starting
Loaded the appropriate driver.
Connected to and created database db
Created table tb
NUM   ADDRESS
1       LONDON
2       PARIS
Dropped table tb
Closed result set and statement
Committed transaction and closed connection
```

You can follow instruction in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/db/derby/code/branches/10.1/java/demo/simple/SimpleApp.java

SimpleApp.java is a demo java class given by ApacheDerby where you can find steps to create a DB using java code.

If needed start from here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/db/derby/code/branches/10.1/java/demo/simple/example.html